# Problem in loading the logo in different URLs in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I have the same html for `Tools.html` and `home.html` but I realized the logo can be loaded in this URL:

```
path('',views.home),
```

But in this URL I do not see the logo and also the favicon:

```
path('Tools/', views.Tools ),
```

[http://127.0.0.1:8000/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOZdC.png)

[http://127.0.0.1:8000/Tools/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBvnR.png)

views:

```
def Tools(request):
    p=product.objects.filter(category__name='Tools')
    return render(request,'Tools.html',{'p':p})
def home(request):
    p=product.objects.filter(category__name='home')
    return render(request,'home.html',{'p':p})
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('Tools/', views.Tools ),
    path('',views.home),
    
]
```

the following codes are for favicon and logo in html file:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="static/logo.png">
<img   class="img" width="270px"  src="static/logo.svg">
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you add the HTML for both pages? Also, your path should start with lowercase - `.../tools/`

Comment: Both of `Tools.html` and `home.html` have the same code.
I tried lowercase but it did not work.

Comment: Did you try adding a height to the `.svg` file?  Something like `<img class="img" height="50" src="static/logo.svg">`. Also might want to double check your static settings are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not hardcode `static/logo.png`, the right way is to use `{% static 'logo.png' %}`. Then it will always search in your `static` folder. You just need to start the template with `{% load static %}`. Assuming, that you have set in settings something like:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and you keep such files in `your_project/static` folder it should work for every level on every app.

More info in [Django DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/)